# How do I make a protected route handler for svelte-kit using static adapter?

Tags: routes, sveltekit

Seems all the solutions out there require ssr (which we are not using). I'm using `adapter-static` and the user is stored in `localStorage` so SSR wouldn't work anyway.

I'm trying to protect pages that require a login in svelte-kit:

```html
<script context="module">
    import { authGuard } from '@lib/guard.js';

    export async function load({ page, fetch, session, context }) {
        return await authGuard({ page, fetch, session, context });
    }
</script>

<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import NavBar from '../components/NavBar.svelte';
    import TopNav from '../components/TopNav.svelte';

    let currentPage;

    page.subscribe((path) => (currentPage = path));
</script>

{#if currentPage.path === '/login'}
    <main class="sans-navbar">
        <TopNav />
        <section>
            <slot />
        </section>
    </main>
{:else}
    <main>
        <NavBar />
        <section>
            <slot />
        </section>
    </main>
{/if}

<style>
    main {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    main.sans-navbar {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    section {
        padding: 2.4rem;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-color: #f2f6fa;
    }
</style>
```

Here's the `guard.js` lib:

```js
import { LoggedIn } from '../stores/user';

export async function authGuard({ page }) {
    console.log(LoggedIn, page);
    if (LoggedIn && page.path === '/login') {
        return { status: 302, redirect: '/' };
    } else if (LoggedIn) {
        return {};
    } else {
        return { status: 302, redirect: '/login' };
    }
}

export default {
    authGuard
};
```

The problem is `LoggedIn` requires localStorage, so the SSR solution won't work.

Comment: As an aside, you should use `$` for stores so that unsubscribing is handled for you.

Rather than storing the value of `page` to `currentPage`, simply use `$page`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm protecting routes.

I have a AuthLayout component that I just wrap around the routes I want to protect. Via this component, you should be able to access localstorage and keep it simpler (IMO).

```js
/* src/lib/components/AuthLayout.svelte */
<script lang="ts">
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import authStore from '$lib/stores/auth';
    import { onDestroy } from 'svelte';

    let ok = false;

    const unsubscribe = authStore.subscribe((state) => {
        if (!state.initializing && state.fbUser !== undefined) {
            ok = state.fbUser !== null;
            if (!ok) {
                goto('/login');
            }
        }
    });

    onDestroy(unsubscribe);
</script>

{#if ok}
    <slot />
{:else}
    <div />
{/if}
```

A few things are happening here. I have a `authStore` that looks like this:

```js
/* src/lib/stores/auth.ts */
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import type { User as FbUser } from 'firebase/auth';

export type AuthStore = {
    initializing: boolean;
    fbUser: FbUser | null | undefined;
};

const authStore = writable<AuthStore>({
    initializing: true,
    fbUser: undefined
});

export default authStore;
```

I am using Firebase auth, so in my top level layout.svelte, I've got the following:

```js
/* src/routes/+layout.svelte */
<script lang="ts">
    import '../app.css';

    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import authStore from '$lib/stores/auth';
    import Footer from './Footer.svelte';
    import Header from './Header.svelte';
    import { auth } from '../firebase';

    onMount(() => {
        auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
            authStore.update((state) => ({
                ...state,
                initializing: false,
                fbUser: user
            }));
        });
    });
</script>

<Header />
<main><slot /></main>
<Footer />
```

I update my authStore whenever the firebase user value changes in my onAuthStateChanged listener.

Now, let's circle back to the AuthLayout component. It grabs the fbUser value from the authStore and if it is null, I redirect to the "/login" route.

The reason there is a `ok` boolean is to avoid the brief flicker when the content you're trying to protect might show. By using the `ok` check, I can ensure that I just show a empty div when there is no firebase user. Otherwise, I will show the protected content via the `<slot />`. There is also an onDestroy callback so I don't have a memory leak with the store subscription.

Finally, here is an example of how I use AuthLayout to protect /welcome:

```js
/* src/routes/welcome/+layout.svelte */
<script>
    import AuthLayout from '$lib/components/AuthLayout.svelte';
</script>

<AuthLayout><slot /></AuthLayout>
```

Voila! The route has been protected.

### Even though I am using prerendering and this way works for me, I believe what you are trying with localstorage should work if you just add onto the AuthLayout.

Note: You may need to do your localstorage check in an onMount.

Answer (score -3):

I played with your code provided on Stack Overflow.
You can find an example using the localStorage to protect some routes.
https://github.com/MathieuDoyon/svelte-kit-static-protected-route

you can change `ssr: false` in svelte.config.js to disable all routes or disable / enable it per pages `export const ssr = false;` https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#ssr-and-javascript-ssr

Setting srr to false on the page will not generate the content into the static HTML page created at from the build.